# How do I properly call an associated model in a component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I get `undefined` when I do the `console.log(this.get('item.product.description'));` in the component object and an error message in ember inspector, console tab:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I suspect this is happening because `item.product.description` is coming from a promise (`async` call). On page load, the promise isn't fulfilled yet. However, what I don't want to do, is create a `.then` block in the component, like:

```
this.get('item.product').then((product) => {
```

This just makes the component not so isolated, since it expects `item.product` to be a promise, instead of an actual string.

What other approaches should I consider?:

```
// Route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});

// Template
{{#each item in model.jobOrders.lastObject.checkout.items}}
  {{product-card item=item}}
{{/each}}
```

The component:

```
// Component template
<p class="name">{{item.product.name}}</p>
<p class="description">{{truncatedDescription}}</p>

// Component object
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  truncatedDescription: Ember.computed('item.product.description', function() {
    console.log(this.get('item.product.description'));

    var truncatedText = this._truncate(this.get('description'), 48);
    console.log(truncatedText);

    return truncatedText;
  }),

  actions: {
    // ...
  },

  // Private
  _truncate(text, limit) {
    if (text.length > limit){
      text = text.substr(0, limit - 3) + '...';
    }
    console.log(text);
    return text;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to pass the description itself to the component instead of the item.

```
// Template
{{#each item in model.jobOrders.lastObject.checkout.items}}
    {{product-card description=item.product.description}}
{{/each}}
```

This way, when `item.product.description` resolves, it will update the computed property `truncatedDescription` in your component.

Comment: Unfortunately, that has the same effect. Still the same error

Comment: If you are getting the `length of undefined` it is because the description will be `undefined` the first time it calculates the computed property. You should add a check if the `text` param is a string in `_truncate` and otherwise just return an empty string.

Comment: So if I turn `_truncate` into a helper instead. I would also need to check if `text` is present right?

Comment: Yes, because the `length` method expects a string. Besides that, it is also cleaner to do param checks in methods where the param might be undefined or null.